# Ensuring a first observable has run before running a second (complex) one

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having some trouble sequencing two observables so that the first runs before the second. I started trying to use `concatMap` without any luck... perhaps this isn't the best option but based on the descriptions of the higher order mapping operators I thought it was the best one.

The first observable that needs to run is very simple:

```
this.workflowService.getFolderActions().subscribe(tasks => {
  this.tasks = tasks;
});
```

The second observable needs the `tasks` (or `this.tasks`) property to run properly. Second observable:

```
this.route.data
.pipe(
  switchMap(x => {
    return this.route.paramMap;
  }))
.subscribe(params => {
  this.paymentId = params.get('id');
  this.task = this.workflowService.getTask(this.paymentId);
  this.paymentData = <PaymentData>this.task.actionData;

  const incompleteOptionalTasks = this.workflowService.getIncompleteOptionalTasks();
  const nextRequiredTask = this.getIncompleteRequired();
  this.nextTask = nextRequiredTask;

  if (!nextRequiredTask && incompleteOptionalTasks) {
    this.nextTask = this.tasks.find(task => task.id !== this.paymentId);
  } else if (nextRequiredTask) {
    this.nextTask = nextRequiredTask;
  }
});
```

With the second observable having a `switchMap` within it, I'm pretty lost. I started trying to write out  a `concatMap` for these two:

```
this.workflowService.getFolderActions().pipe(
  tap(tasks => this.tasks = tasks),
  concatMap(tasks => {
    this.route.data.pipe(
      switchMap(x => {
        return this.route.paramMap;
      })
    )
  })
);
```

...but I'm getting an error: `'tasks' is declared but its value is never read.` I'm sure however that I'm not approaching this correctly, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing it in following way:

```js
this.workflowService.getFolderActions().
  pipe(
    tap(tasks => this.tasks = tasks),
    switchMapTo(this.route.paramMap)
  )
  .subscribe(params => {
    this.paymentId = params.get('id');
    this.task = this.workflowService.getTask(this.paymentId);
    this.paymentData = <PaymentData>this.task.actionData;

    const incompleteOptionalTasks = this.workflowService.getIncompleteOptionalTasks();
    const nextRequiredTask = this.getIncompleteRequired();
    this.nextTask = nextRequiredTask;

    if (!nextRequiredTask && incompleteOptionalTasks) {
      this.nextTask = this.tasks.find(task => task.id !== this.paymentId);
    } else if (nextRequiredTask) {
      this.nextTask = nextRequiredTask;
    }
  });
```

Optionally you might want to receive the `tasks` in the subscription function instead of saving it globally:

```js
 this.workflowService.getFolderActions().
  pipe(
    tap(tasks => this.tasks = tasks),
    withLatestFrom(this.route.paramMap)
  )
  .subscribe(([tasks, params]) => {
    this.paymentId = params.get('id');
    this.task = this.workflowService.getTask(this.paymentId);
    this.paymentData = <PaymentData>this.task.actionData;

    const incompleteOptionalTasks = this.workflowService.getIncompleteOptionalTasks();
    const nextRequiredTask = this.getIncompleteRequired();
    this.nextTask = nextRequiredTask;

    if (!nextRequiredTask && incompleteOptionalTasks) {
      this.nextTask = tasks.find(task => task.id !== this.paymentId);
    } else if (nextRequiredTask) {
      this.nextTask = nextRequiredTask;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Wow this is so incredibly helpful--I was not as familiar with the `withLatestFrom` and `switchMapTo` operators -- reading up on them now. Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `switchMap` operator is chosen correctly because it has access to value from the first observable where you can operate on this value, and next, you have to return Observable too.

```
this.workflowService.getFolderActions()
 .pipe(
  switchMap((tasks ) => {
   this.tasks = tasks;
   return this.route.paramMap;
 })
 .subscribe(() => ...)
```